# iOS: Switching between button overlays on top of Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, user-interface, layout, view

this is my first time working with XCode, and so I am having a lot of issues trying to figure out how to do certain things, mainly UI related.

Currently I am having three issues:

1. I have two buttons, and I want them both to be half the width of the screen, but I just can't get it to work (I want to show a picture, but I am also new to stackoverflow, and I don't have enough reputation).
2. I want the buttons to be on top of a Google Map, and as of now, the buttons aren't visible when I run the application (I'm thinking the map is on top of them, maybe).
3. When I click one of the buttons, I want a different set of buttons to replace the former ones. e.g. Click a button to "Start Game", and then a new set of buttons "Easy", "Normal", and "Hard" show up.

I hope you can understand what I mean. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for first question answer is use UIsegmented Control. check out this link
[Uisegemnted control tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/create-segmented-control-ios7)

2) put your mapview below the segmented control and adjust the size of it.

3) for third answer there are many option. you can use alert view or make a custom view and put three buttons on it and then hide the view. on the click of start game just unhidden the view.